# EMACS, text seems to be shifted

Tags: encoding, emacs, utf-8, cygwin

Using,

EMACS 24.5.1 (encoding: UTF-8 (dos/unix))

OS: Windows 8

Terminal: mintty with UTF-8 under Cygwin

Problem:

- Any existing text file that I open in EMACS does not hold its indentation (text is shifted either left or right of its original position). The same text file if I open it in VIM in the same terminal session, seems to be have the correct alignment.
- This happens to every text file that I open in EMACS.
- I assumed the problem might be with encoding or EOL. So I tried changing the encoding of the terminal output in EMACS(using C-x RET r RET | C-x RET t RET) but that did not help.

I have been reading the official manual but can't seem to solve this issue.

Has anybody got any suggestion of how I should correct this indentation/alignment/EOL problem?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I saw some similar emacs encoding problems on here but none of them seemed to have helped.

Comment: 1. Say what you did. 2. Say what you saw, and what you expected to see instead. 3. Be specific. Preferably, provide  a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). As it stands now, your question is unclear and so risks being closed.

Comment: @Drew sorry I am completely new with EMACS. Upon your suggestion, I have re-phrased the question.

Comment: Are you using tabs for indentation? (Tabs are designed such that they can be displayed at any user-defined width. For example, they may appear to be 8 spaces wide in Vim and 4 spaces wide in Emacs.)

Comment: @Chris yes I am using tabs for indentation and theses are (1 tab = 4 white space character). If i remember correctly the default in Emacs is (1 tab = 8 whitespace char).  Maybe that is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Thanks that did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the tab size and nothing to do with the encoding.

Emacs is actually pretty awesome in detecting the encoding.

The tab size = 8 white space character in Emacs by default. All my other editors I had set to 4 white space characters hence they all seem to be shifted or lost their indentation when opened in Emacs.

I have used the below configuration in my .emacs file to correct this to tabs = 4 white space char.

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

Thanks again Chris for the solution